# Xamarin Forms Image not showing in listview

Tags: c#, android, image, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to display a `/!\` icon in my listview. Unfortunately, it's not showing up anywhere.

I am 100% positive it's in the right place in both the iOS and Android app. I have double checked that it is a Android resource (as per screenshot below)
[image]

The code used to initialize the image: `alarmIcon = new Image { Source = "warning.png" };`

After initialization I put it in an AlarmPageItem object which as an Image property. This gets added to the listview.
I have checked that I matched the bindings with the `AlarmPageItem` properties. (The text does get shown).

I am at a loss why it wouldn't work...

Things I tried

1. Checked case of image and source declaration
2. Checked the build action and copy to output directory
3. Checked binding matching
4. Tried building to phone instead of xamarin live player
5. Checked image location

Code:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="OSIApp.Pages.AlarmPage"
         Title="Alarm Log">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="listView" 
                  ItemTapped="OnItemTapped" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label x:Name="alarmTimeLabel"
                                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                       Text="{Binding DateTime}"/>
                                <Image x:Name="alarmIconImage" 
                                       Source="{Binding AlarmImage}"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                            <Label x:Name="alarmTextLabel"
                                   FontSize="14"
                                   VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                   FontFamily="Avenir Next"
                                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                                   Text="{Binding AlarmText}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

```
    public partial class AlarmPage : ContentPage
{
    private List<AlarmPageItem> listViewItems;

    private Image alarmIcon;

    public AlarmPage ()
    {
        listViewItems = new List<AlarmPageItem>();
        alarmIcon = new Image { Source = "warning.png" };
        PopulateList();

        InitializeComponent();

        listView.ItemsSource = listViewItems;
    }

    private void OnItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e == null) return; // has been set to null, do not 'process' tapped event
        Debug.WriteLine("Tapped: " + e.Item);
        ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null; // de-select the row
    }

    private void PopulateList()
    {


        listViewItems.Add(new AlarmPageItem() {AlarmImage = alarmIcon, AlarmText = "The front is too heavy", DateTime = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()});
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you display the whole code you implemented for the ListView? It's easier to find where the issue might be.

Comment: @apineda added the code now :)

Comment: If you give your image a height request does it show up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are binding as "Source" of your `Image` in the XAML an `Image` object you are creating in your code behind.

Update your `AlarmPageItem` class by making the `AlarmImage` property either an `ImageSource` or just a simple `string`.

Something like:

```
class AlarmPageItem
{
    public string AlarmImage { get; set; }

    public string AlarmText { get; set; }

    //Just a suggestion: Change this property name for something different as it 
    //can create some confusion.
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

     ...

    // Add any other properties your class might have.
}
```

Once the above is updated just change your code to set the name of the image in the `PopulateList` method

```
private void PopulateList()
{
    listViewItems.Add(new AlarmPageItem() {AlarmImage = "warning.png", AlarmText = "The front is too heavy", DateTime = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()});
}
```

Hope this helps.-